# Community Bulletin - ends in xx hours

Tags: discussion, community-bulletin

I think I'm misunderstanding the "Community Bulletin", will delete my question when I'll find it's very stupid.

[image]

What exactly "ends in 13 hours"? Is it a special post? I didn't see we are voting for something there, it was a regular question.

Comment: See the "event" to the left of the link? The "event" ends in 13 hours.

Comment: @Oded But why is this "event". I saw a question there.. What am I missing?

Comment: @Oded: does that mean that the mighty dup hammer gets removed in 13h

Comment: The *event* ends in 13 hours. It's just that someone wanted to pin the 'dupehammer' post for a fixed amount of time to the board.

Comment: @Mat: No, just that the message will be removed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters now that's useful info worth being posted as answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I understand that, but it is indeed  confusing.

Comment: It was one choice for getting that post onto the community bulletin, for a short time. It could also have been "featured", but that would take someone removing the tag later on (or have it remain there for 30 days). Setting as an "event" controls timing without user (mod) intervention.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The community managers and / or moderators wanted to publicise the new Dupe Hammer feature, and the best way to do that is to create an event message. These are pinned to the community bulletin for a fixed amount of time; items are normally listed based on post popularity.

It's a bit of an abuse of a feature, but it works.

In 13 hours the *event* ends, which means the post will no longer be listed on the CB. That's all.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think any of the CMs did it, but one of the mods.

Comment: OP asked that as a question, who decided to turn it into an *event*? How the procedure works?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I am not a moderator anywhere, I don't know how it works *exactly*. I can imagine there is a page somewhere where you create an event with a link to a post to explain the event. Here that link is the Dupe Hammer post.

Comment: [I believe @Robert Harvey might have been the one who added it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619682/is-there-a-way-to-remove-a-whole-property-from-a-js-object/23619698#comment36263853_23619698).